# How to override a superclass' property with more specific types?

Tags: objective-c, properties, subclassing, overriding, synthesis

**The Scenario**
I have a situation where a base class called `AbstractRequest` has a delegate property of type `id <AbstractRequestDelegate>` declared in the header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AbstractRequestDelegate> delegate;
```

The abstract delegate protocol contains a few required methods, and as indicated with the word 'abstract', both the `AbstractRequest` and the `AbstractRequestDelegate` are intended to be subclasses/extended.

One example of this would be the subclass ConcreteRequest and extended protocol ConcreteRequestDelegates, that both add extra methods to the abstract ones. The intention is that both the abstract and concrete class methods can send messages to the single assigned delegate instance.

At a certain point in time the ConcreteRequest would like to call a method on the delegate that is defined by ConcreteRequestDelegate. Because the type of the delegate is id , the compiler will give a warning that this method might not be implemented.

> ConcreteRequest.m:38: warning:
>   property 'delegate' requires method
>   '-delegate' to be defined - use
>   @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a
>   method implementation

**The Problem**
This warning is justified, for the property is after all typed to `id <AbstractRequestDelegate>`. In order to fix this, I want to make clear to the compiler that the delegate assigned to the concrete instance must be of type `id <ConcreteRequestDelegate>`. This sounded perfectly reasonable to me, so I put in a new property in the ConcreteRequest header, hoping to override the abstract one:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ConcreteRequestDelegate> delegate;
```

But this is where the compiler disagrees with me, probably with good reason. I would have thought it would give a warning for overriding a super class' property with the wrong type, but instead it just demands me to re-synthesize this new property. I don't want to go there, because then the super class' methods won't have access to the same delegate property.

**The Question**
Is there a way to 're-declare' the property in the concrete subclass with the added type information? Or can you spot the error in my thinking, for maybe this is a fairly common problem that I just haven't come across until now?

Cheers,
EP.

*P.S. All class and protocol names appearing in this work are fictitious. Any resemblance to real class and protocol names, open source or patented, is purely coincidental.*

Comment: lol on P.S.  :D... could you post the code for all the interface and classes... you explanation is too long

Comment: This already cost me half an hour, maybe someone else can see through the many words. If all fails, I'll invest the time to pseudo-code these classes.

Comment: :D why do you thing re synthesizing will create a problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The warning already gave the right clue. I used @dynamic in the overriding subclass and all is good.

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you did in the subclass to get this to work? also, do you still believe this is a good pattern?

Comment: For anyone who comes across this later, what this answer is saying is that if you simply redeclare the property in the subclass it effectively works but there's a warning.  If you then go into your implementation section in your .m file and add the line "@dynamic samevariablename", it effectively causes the warning/problem on the @property declaration to go away.  It may not be expected that it will do this because the warning is in a difference place than the place the problem is solved, but it does.  It just worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just synthesize `id<ConcreteRequestDelegate>delegate` in the  `ConcreteRequest.m` it will work fine...It won't create any problem.