# Subclassing and inheritance in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a class called `AbstractBook`, which has a property:

```
@property(strong) AbstractPage *page;
```

Now say I have a subclass of `AbstractBook` called `WhiteBook` and a subclass of `AbstractPage` called `WhitePage`. I want the `WhiteBook` class to inherit the `page` object, but in this class, I want it to be the specific `WhitePage` class instead of `AbstractPage`.

So, in `WhiteBook`, I just redeclared the property as `WhitePage`:

```
@property(strong) WhitePage *page;
```

However, I am getting a warning: `WhitePage is incompatible with AbstractPage inherited from AbstractBook.` What is the right way to implement what I'm going for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is fundamentally impossible.  Don't forget that this:

```
@property(strong) AbstractPage *page;
```

declares a getter **and a setter**.

Generally speaking (this is for OO programming generally, not just Objective-C), there is no problem with an override getter returning a subclass of the return type of the super class implementation because this does not break the API contract.  In your case, an instance of `WhitePage` is also an `AbstractPage`.

However, the setter is different.  You can't restrict the type of the parameter because your subclass must be useable anywhere where an `AbstractBook` is used, so code that invokes the setter on something that it thinks is an `AbstractBook` is entitled to pass in an instance of **any** `AbstractPage` subclass, because that is what the API says.

I think what I would do is add a method to `AbstractBook` called something like

```
-(bool) isLegalPage: (AbstractPage) aPage;
```

that returns true always in the base class but true only for white pages in `WhiteBook`.  Then I would manually implement the setter  as follows:

```
-(void) setPage: (AbstractPage*) aPage
{
    if (![self isLegalPage: aPage])
    {
        // throw an exception or do other error notification
    }
    else
    {
        Do the assignment according to reference count/ARC/GC model
    }
}
```

Document that the setter will throw an exception if the page is not legal and that people should use the `isLegalPage:` method to test this.

The alternative id to have a read only property and use different setters in the base class and subclass, or don't have a setter at all in the base class.

Answer (score 3):

There is no property type [*covariance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) in Objective C, so if you want a property returning a subclass of `AbstractPage`, you need to define a separate property, say `whitePage`, in your `WhiteBook` subclass. You can return the same value from your `page` property, too, and it would work. Moreover, if your users call methods on the `AbstractPage*`, they would not even need to cast it to `WhitePage*`.

Comment: So create a new property in my subclass called whitePage, and implement a custom getter method which returns the superclass object?

Comment: @mohabitar Yes, that would be one solution. If the base class is abstract, do not synthesize the `page` property: this will let each subclass of the book to use a properly typed ivar for its own subclass of the page.

Comment: Wait don't synthesize in the abstract class? Then how would I set it initially? I don't want to set the specific whitePage property, I just want to set the AbstractPage page, while the getter returns the specific type..

Comment: @mohabitar You can definitely reuse the synthesized property from the abstract class, but then you'd need to cast the variable in your code if you want to access the properties of the page from ivar, or use the property that makes the cast for you.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to program to the interface not implementation.

======================

## Option: 1

If your Whitebook truly is a descendant of AbstractBook you don't need to make WhiteBook have a new property called "page", since your AbstractBook already declares it your WhiteBook gets it for free.

As long as your WhitePage inherits from AbstractPage you should be able to cast your page object as a WhitePage. Then you get all original functionality of AbstractPage, plus that of WhitePage.

So you shouldn't need to re-declare page in Whitebook. If you go to your Whitebook.h file and delete this line

```
@property(strong) WhitePage *page;
```

Then go into your Whitebook.m file and type self.page you shouldn't get any compile warnings. Then you can cast page as WhitePage and you should be good to go.

WARNING: This means you will need to cast page as a WhitePage where ever you use it, which is not ideal.

======================

## Option: 2

You may also try leaving the code as you have it, but make sure to synthesize the "page" prop again in WhiteBook.

======================

## Option: 3

You may also try leaving the code as you have it, but make sure to use @dynamic for the "page" prop in WhiteBook. Then implement the getter yourself and return a WhitePage instead of an AbstractPage.

Comment: I think I'm gonna go with option 3. However, would it be ok to have the property synthesized in the abstract class and dynamic in the subclass?

Comment: Option 3 would be exceedingly outside the norm.

Comment: Really? So which would be the standard? I could use option 2, but then the warning would stick around right?

Comment: Either create a second, more specific, property or use a return type of `(id)` (and file a bug against Objective-C asking for co-variance support).

Answer (score 0):

[How to override a superclass' property with more specific types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896085/how-to-override-a-superclass-property-with-more-specific-types)

Normally if you use `@synthesize` in your `AbstractBook` class and `@dynamic` in your `WhiteBook` class, it should work fine (unless, of course, you use the `AbstractPage` synthesized method to assign a non-`WhitePage` to `page`).