# Is this Swift property overriden or hidden?

Tags: swift

`AVAsset` has a `tracks` property...

```
var tracks: [AVAssetTrack] { get }
```

`AVComposition` inherits from `AVAsset` and also has a tracks property...

```
var tracks: [AVCompositionTrack] { get }
```

(`AVCompositionTrack` inherits from `AVAssetTrack`.)

Is `AVComposition.tracks` overriding `AVAsset.tracks` or is it hiding it?

Comment: Bear in mind none of those types are Swift types, they're all implemented in Obj-C. And in Obj-C [You can override a superclass property with a more specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896085/how-to-override-a-superclass-property-with-more-specific-types). If these were pure Swift types, this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: So how have they got around the Swift compiler in this instance?

Comment: Because there is no Swift compiler involved. This is ObjC code. It's just an imported header in Swift.